# How to serialize Objects in C++ via copying memory?

Tags: c++, arrays, serialization, object

Is it possible in C++ to serialize an object by taking a pointer of the first address of the object and increment this pointer till the end of the object is reached?

If it's possible, how can I find the first memory adress of the object and in which data type should I store the values? And how could I build the object on the other side?

Comment: why do you want to serialize. is it to send the object to another process or computer, or so you can write it to a file?

Comment: Here are some things you'll need to consider: (1) how to deal with classes that have non-trivial constructors; (2) how to deal with pointers/references contained within the object; (3) how to deal with virtual base classes.

Comment: maybe sending it over a tcp socket or something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is relatively easy to do in some very restrictive circumstances ([POD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146452/what-are-pod-types-in-c) with no pointers/references; same OS, CPU architecture and the C++ compiler on both ends of the serialization pipe).

There is a number of issues that complicate matters in the more general case:

1. dealing with classes that have non-trivial constructors/destructors;
2. dealing with pointers/references contained within the object;
3. cycles in the pointer/reference graph;
4. polymorphism;
5. dealing with virtual base classes;
6. endianness;
7. field alignment, padding etc;
8. the width of primitive types (`int` on one platform isn't necessarily the same size as `int` on another);
9. versioning so that new fields can be added without breaking stuff.

Comment: Even in a POD containing no pointers or references it can fail due to padding between fields.

Comment: @Jerry: depends what aix means by, "same OS, CPU architecture and the C++ compiler". If the two implementations share a C ABI, then they'll necessarily have the same layout for POD structs. But compiler options can affect that.

Comment: @SteveJessop: it's pretty common to use things like `#pragma pack` to force a specific alignment for structs used in the ABI, but still have variation in other structs, so sharing an ABI doesn't necessarily mean much.

Answer (score 2):

The procedure you describe would create a flat copy of the object. If that object contained pointers or references itself, this scheme would break.

If you want to serialize objects, use a library like [Boost.Serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/serialization/doc/index.html).

Comment: And even if it doesn't it's completely non-portable as it exposes implementation details like alignment, padding, endian and the sizes of types.

Answer (score 0):

There are several serialization formats (XDR, ASN1, JSON, YAML), techniques, and libraries (like [s11n](http://s11n.net/) for C++)